# How to refer to a capture group within a regex?

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to refer to a capture group within a regular expression?

E.g if you have 2 strings, one is:

```
Person: Name is Bob. Type: Person
```

And the other:

```
Animal: Name is Jupiter. Type: Animal
```

Can you do something like this:

```
(Person|Animal): Name is (.+). Type: $1
```

The idea being, to use the result of the first capture group to determine whether its a person or animal, and then putting that result where `$1` is, to complete the sentence.

Can something like this be done, if not with $1, then with any other operator?

Comment: This kind of thing is dependent on the regex engine you're referring to. What regex engine are you using, or, at least, what language are you using (so we can guess)?

Comment: @KeithGaughan I'm using PHP. I'll add it.

Comment: Why not accept the right answer?

Answer (score 2):

If it's PCRE you're referring to, you can use numbered backreferences in the pattern (`'\1'`, &c.) or named ones (`'(?P=pattern-name)'`).

Comment: Here's the bit of the PHP manual you're looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php